# MYSQL table won't open in localhost on my mac

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

MYSQL table won't open in my localhost on my mac.

I have other tables that open fine in localhost except this one table. It opens fine in MAMP or phpMyAdmin but not localhost..it is driving me nuts..i imported the table from phpMyAdmin on my web server..other tables that i imported work fine. Please help.

i checked for file permission and all is ok

apache_error.log

[Mon Dec 08 11:31:52 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.6.2 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8zc DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.20.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

mysql_errorlog.err

141208 11:31:55 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.38'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 8889  Source distribution

Comment: What error are you getting while importing table?

Comment: i am not getting an error..thats what i don't get

Comment: Is query logging on? Hosts file maybe?

Comment: how would i go about finding that out?